# Add hyperlink "improve tag wiki" to tag hoverbox for easier tag editing?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, hyperlinks

When you hover your mouse over a tag that you see used in a question, you get something like this.

[image]

Some of these tags are still not defined but are frequently used. To edit them, you need to click on the tag itself and find the link that says "improve tag wiki". As a first time user, I didn't know about editing tags until I read the [tag editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/254/tag-editor) description. I then had to google how to edit tags because I couldn't find where the "improve tag wiki" button was. In my mind, I was just looking for a button that says "edit" on the [hoverbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoverbox) above.

[image]

I suggest we add a "improve tag wiki" or "edit" hyperlink to this hoverbox to make editing tags more accessible to everyone. This way, we'll have less empty tags that need edited and editing will be more user friendly.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think it's a (partially) good idea.

As a newer user, I see an extremely high value in the tag excerpts for classification, although I do not see as much value in editing the tag info wikis.

I would be in favor of a feature that wold improve the ability to find & fix incomplete tag excerpts. Currently, you can only sort by `popular`, `name`, and `new`. Being able to quickly find a list of tags that are not synonyms and have a blank tag excerpt would be useful.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a bad idea:

You have to take the time to read the full tag-wiki and tag-excerpt before you can be sure your concern isn't already addressed appropriately for most worthwhile edits anyway.